# Resizing shapes using an absolute value in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, resize, illustrator-scripting

I want to clone and resize a bunch of the same shape.

I want them to all be **X** smaller/bigger than the previous shape, where **X = absolute value** (not a relative percentage).

Currently, I can only find ways to make things resized using a percentage (each copy will be 20% smaller or whatever). I can't find a way to make each shape *40*pt smaller (if it was a square at *200x200*, next one should be *160x160*, *120x120*).

I feel like there is a setting in Illustrator, I just can't seem to find it.

---

- I don't mind doing it once and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat a bunch of times.
- I'm hoping to be able to change the **width** and **height** with separate values (for non equilateral shapes).

Answer (score 1):

Constraining Width and Height proportions, at the end of the width size add `+ quantity` to increase.

[image]

To duplicate, at the end of the width size add `+ quantity` to increase and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this beforehand. I can't seem to copy the shape when I apply it though.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about that. However, I still can't enter it in once and then just repeat it a bunch of times. Also, I can't change the values for width and height and adjust together.

Comment: Try the blend tool

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with was to use the *Tranform Panel* and an action which duplicates my shapes 
 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) with the function key <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Select the shape and press <kbd>F2</kbd>

I open the transform panel, and with *Constrain Proportions* on, I enter `-40` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>F2</kbd> again and repeat.

Mouse is in the same spot, so it isn't that hard to *click* and *type -40* and then hit *enter*.

[image: GIF showing process]

---

Problems with this:

1. It's still very much manual.
2. You can only do this to shapes which are of equal **width** x **height**.